# Containers keep restarting

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've started running kubernetes on GCE.
I setup a 3x f1-micro cluster and Im running:
 * influxdb x1
 * Grafana x1
 * nginx x1
 * phpfpm7 x1
 * golang x2
 * redis x1

I keep having all my container restarting regularly, in 1h time, grafana restarted 4x, redis 3x, my golangs 2x, nginx 4x.
On my local, they never restart and are perfectly working fine...
The logs don't tell me anything about why it rebooted.

1. For people using kubernetes, how often do your containers restart?
2. Could it be a perf issue?
3. I have also mounted persistentdisk for grafana and influxdb, but it seems after each restart, the data is wiped. Any idea?

thanks for your help!

Comment: after looking at kubectl logs YOURPODNAME --previous
I realized that there's an external shutdown coming from somewhere. Is there any specific policy for pod restart in Kubernetes?

Comment: Can you look at your operations history for GCE to see if the VMs are being replaced? How much memory are you allocating to each of your pods?

Comment: The VMs have the same names, so I guess they didn't change.
These have standard 512MB x3VMs.

Everything was running fine in the past on ONE only coreos instance VM with 512MB and one vcpu (lowest Digital Ocean conf).

Is there a lot of overhead with kubernetes?

Comment: If you launch a cluster with all of the default settings, there can be a decent amount of overhead -- there is a logging pod on each machine collecting logs and sending them to google cloud logging, there is a heapster pod running that collects monitoring data about all of your pods, there is the kube-ui pod that exposes a simple UI for your cluster, there is the horizontal pod autoscaler controller pod, and there is the ingress pod (for L7 configuration). Taken together, these use quite a few resources on your (tiny) VMs.

Comment: I set the autoscale feature and the cluster went up to 9x machines in order to let the load be below 60%.
Is there anyway to deactivate those pods?

Comment: You can disable some of them using the [update cluster](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters/update#ClusterUpdate) API call. You can turn off heapster by setting `desiredMonitoringService` to false, and you can disable the HPA and ingress controllers using the [AddonsConfig](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#AddonsConfig) sub-message. Logging can only be enabled/disabled at cluster creation time, and the UI & DNS pods cannot be disabled.

Comment: thanks! I will try this out and update you on the output!

Comment: I recreated the cluster, without logging and monitoring, it's way leaner, I'm around 40% cpu load with the same containers and f1-micros.

Comment: @VincentSerpoul Thank you for your `--previous` comment. That is GOLD.  I had no idea that even existed.  End of the logs was the panic and stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I actually played around with the resources and limits of each container, deactivated heapster on the kube-system namespace and everthing runs now fine!

Answer (score 0):

[cobbling together an answer from our discussion in the comment thread above]

It sounds like your cluster is generally overloaded. By default, when you launch a cluster using Google Container Engine a number of cluster add ons are pre-installed to add additional features to your cluster. If you want to run a cluster with less overhead and you don't care about the optional features, you can disable them (most at any time, but a few only at cluster creation time).

Comment: it is indeed overloaded, I use it mostly for QA, to check everything is fine before going to production.
I am using a normal setup for the production cluster.

Very happy with kubernetes overall!

Comment: You said you are using f1-micro, which I think is just too small to really be effective